# Profiling django app hosted on apache2

Tags: django, web-applications, apache2, profiling, performance

I am having a django app which was hosted on apache2. The webapp basically makes a request to a server using thrift and renders the output on the webpage. I notice that webapp is really slow. I am not sure if it is machine problem or the API problem. I verified the API's and they are returning responses in few milliseconds. I am not sure, if django is the problem. Is there a way to profile the webapp. I am using python 2.5.2.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing would be to enable logging, if you are using the latest django 1.3, it is nicely integrated with the python logging module, see:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/

here you can define a Formatter which saves the time each log message is written, see example in django docs:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/#an-example